# Web Audio API - Sound in Chrome/Safari but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I can play audio just fine in Chrome/Safari, but in Firefox I just get silence with no errors so I don't know what is going on.

This is my code:

```
const lowpassFilterNode = audioContext.createBiquadFilter()
lowpassFilterNode.type = "lowpass"
lowpassFilterNode.frequency.value = lowpassCutoff
lowpassFilterNode.Q.value = 5
const gainNode = audioContext.createGain()
gainNode.gain.value = volume
await audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule("./soundtouch.js")
const source = createScheduledSoundTouchNode(audioContext, audioBuffer)
source.parameters.get("rate").value = audioSpeed
source.parameters.get("pitch").value = pitchCorrect
source.loop = true
await functions.timeout(200)
source.connect(gainNode)
gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination)
source.start(0, offset)
```

I think the problem is with soundtouch. I am using the library here:
https://github.com/DanceCuts/soundtouchjs-scheduled-audio-worklet/blob/master/src/createScheduledSoundTouchNode.js

But I didn't find anything that is obviously wrong in this code. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Any console errors?  Any auto-play issues?

Comment: No errors, I start the audio after a user gesture. I do get this warning in the console: `BiquadFilterNode channel count changes may produce audio glitches.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `process()` function of the `ScheduledSoundTouchWorklet` checks if there are any inputs before it does anything meaningful. That actually makes sense since an input can be an empty array. For some reason Chrome and Safari fill this array at some point with zeros even though there is nothing connected to the input. Firefox does not.

https://github.com/DanceCuts/soundtouchjs-scheduled-audio-worklet/blob/e12eefaa52eadc1ffb6d80741e9aa84dea60d6cf/src/ScheduledSoundTouchWorklet.js#L131

Firefox is actually correct but `@dancecuts/soundtouchjs-scheduled-audio-worklet` expects the wrong behaviour. You can use that to your advantage by connecting something to the input of the `ScheduledSoundTouchNode`.

```js
const constantSourceNode = new ConstantSourceNode(audioContext);

constantSourceNode.connect(source);
constantSourceNode.start();
```

Comment: That was it, thank you! I actually fixed it just by adding the line `if (!inputs[0].length) inputs = [[new Array(128).fill(0)], [new Array(128).fill(0)]]` to process.